# Search comments, from other commentors; on question/answers you authored, or have commented on

Tags: support, data-explorer

I have taken a look at [http://data.stackexchange.com/unix and linuxmeta/queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linuxmeta/queries), and tried to craft a query to return the above, without success. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an existing query called [Where did I meet this user](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/query/122341/where-did-i-meet-this-user) that seems to match what you're looking for

Comment: If I am understanding the resultset here correctly (Return comments where user A has commented on their own Q/A), this isn't quite what I was looking for. Put another way, I am interested in finding Q/A's that user A has contributed to (in any way) that user B has, also. Also, I notice that no matter what UserID I enter, the UserDisplayName field remains empty for every row.

Comment: @user66001 Given a user ID, this shows all comments on posts that user wrote or commented on. I'm not sure what you're looking for if not that; do you want to limit it to comments by a particular user? I don't know what's up with UserDisplayName, it seems to just be empty most of the time; I'm not sure what it's for, it might only be filled when the user is deleted

Comment: I am interested in finding Q/A's that user A has contributed to (in any way) that user B has, also. Also, what does the `AND UserId != ##UserId##;` line in the current version exclude?

Comment: @user66001 You mean [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/query/122341/where-did-i-meet-this-user)?

Comment: This does seem to be it, however is missing stuff, but if it is, is missing stuff from ~11 hours ago. Should it be? Also, what does the `AND UserId != ##UserId##;` line in the first version exclude?

Comment: @user66001 It excludes comments posted by whichever user ID you specified; it was an attempt to exclude comments by yourself. That site doesn't show live data, it's usually a few days behind

Comment: Thanks; I see; Perhaps you could put the query from http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/query/122341/where-did-i-meet-this-user into your answer, instead, now?